# How do i restrict usage of my custom annotation? (dart)

Tags: dart, annotations, static-analysis

When i have a custom annotation like this:

```dart
class FieldAnnotation{
  const FieldAnnotation();
}
```

How do i restrict the usage of that annotation to only be applied on fields. Specifically, how do i generate a warning or an error on static analysis?

```
@FieldAnnotation() // should show a warning or an error
class Test{
  @FieldAnnotation() // should have no problems 
  final String id;  

  Test({required this.id});
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hoped, someone had already answered your question. I'm also searching for more detailed information about custom dart annotations.

But perhaps i have found the answer inside the meta package - in [meta-meta.dart](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/main/pkg/meta/lib/meta_meta.dart) - to be precise.

As I understand, you can annotate your custom annotation class (annotation definition, not the annotated elements) with `@Target(targets)` where *targets* is a `Set<TargetKind>` where *TargetKind* is an enum.

Also interesting to see, that it is possible to write an *extension* on an enum what they did with *TargetKind*.